# alert msg onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to invoke a button click from inside a .cshtml file:

```
  <input type="button" id="ImageHosting" value="To Image Hosting" onclick="ImageHosting_Click()"/>
```

This is the .js file:

```
 function ImageHosting_Click() {
               $("#ImageHosting").click(function () {
                   alert("test");
               });
       }
```

I am not able to get the alert message. Any idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
// Try like this:

$("#ImageHosting").click(function() {
  alert("test");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="ImageHosting" value="To Image Hosting" />
```

Answer (score 6):

You are binding the event handler inline in HTML also you are using jQuery to bind again inside the function which is not correct.

Just remove the inline onclick,

```
<input type="button" id="ImageHosting" value="To Image Hosting" />
```

And change JS

```
$(document).ready ( function () {
    $("#ImageHosting").click(function () {
       alert("test");
    });
});
```

Incase if this button is inserted dynamically then,

```
$(document).ready ( function () {
    //replace document below with enclosing container but below will work too
    $(document).on('click', "#ImageHosting", function () {
       alert("test");
    });
});
```

Use `.live/.delegate` if you older version of jQuery ( < 1.7)

Comment: @GoldenUser There are 3 possible cases that I could think of, 1. You might have a script error.. so check your error console. 2. You might be adding the button dynamically, in which case you need to use .on or .live/.delegate based on jQuery version. 3. You might have duplicate ID of the same button. Please check for those.

Comment: I'm not getting any javascript error. I've tried both the solutions as mentioned but nothing works!

Comment: Ok - this might sound crazy but I used firebug to run through the .js file got the alert. I switched it off and reran my application and I am getting the alerts now! Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 6):

Conversely to SKS's answer (keeping the inline `onclick` attribute):

```
<input type="button" id="ImageHosting" value="To Image Hosting" onclick="ImageHosting_Click()"/>
```

And

```
function ImageHosting_Click(){
    alert("test");
}
```

Or even all in one:

```
<input type="button" id="ImageHosting" value="To Image Hosting" onclick="alert('test');"/>
```